# Positioning custom UINavigationBar Back Button

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard

I've built a **custom back button** in `UINavigationBar`.
I've managed to change `backIndicatorImage` with a custom `UIView` and It works just how it is supposed to be.

The issue is that I'm unable to move it to the left side.

[image: SimulatorImage]

And this is view hierarchy:

[image]

And this is the code in `prepare for segue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let backImage = UIImage(view: backButton).withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Add action for barbuttonitem then it will work

Comment: @selvaraj We need to reposition it, action has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think dimension of your back button image is too high, try reducing it something below 100 px

Comment: @Vikky Width is same as it appears(grey area). Check out view hierarchy, there's padding on both side of button. Padding that i didn't mention.